# gnuplot data interpolation method for smoothing of data

Tags: plot, matplotlib, gnuplot

Friends, i have some vast amount of data to be printed on a graph using gnuplot.
Since the number of points in the graph is too large, i am using a cspline data interpolation method to smoothen the data. But the interpolation method is skipping some outliers which may be important in the analysis of performance of program. How should I make sure that the extreme outliers (values differing by more than x) are not missed by the gnuplot function.

Here is the code i am using to generate plots.

```
plot data_file binary format='%uint64 %double %double %double' using 1:2 smooth csplines title "Kernel hit-rate"  with lines, \ 
 data_file binary format='%uint64 %double %double %double' using 1:3 smooth csplines title "User hit-rate"    with lines, \
 data_file binary format='%uint64 %double %double %double' using 1:4 smooth csplines title "Overall hit-rate" with lines
```

The graphs generated are given below :

[image: With CSplines]

[image: Without CSplines]

I want gnuplot to smoothen points only if they are not too far (a configurable parameter) ?? Also can you suggest any other plotting tool that can do what i require ??

Comment: Please don't go into the semantics of the graph.

Comment: I'm confused, is the first plot with csplines and the second plot without?  If so, what exactly are you trying to accomplish with csplines (i.e. what is wrong with the second graph?)

Comment: (1) The first plot is with csplines and the second part is without csplines. (2) As you can notice, in the second graph, we can see some yvalues reaching 0.8 to 0.9 . Unfortunately, the first graph's peak  for the x-range around (5000) is around 0.1

Comment: But what is wrong with the second plot?  If you want to keep the spurious peaks, it seems that using csplines is exactly the opposite of what you are trying to accomplish. -- As a side note, using `set samples N` could be used to increase your sampling frequency which would probably make the first graph look more like the second one (with a reasonably large N)...

Comment: Also, gnuplot has a variety of smoothing options:  From the builtin help: `      smooth {unique | frequency | cumulative | kdensity | csplines | acsplines
 | bezier | sbezier}` -- You could try some of the others and see how it looks.

Comment: @mgilson thanks for the reply. The problem is that I want to smooth out the values that are very close to each other but not the outiers (spurious peaks). I will try for suggestion and reply ASAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could probably accomplish this with a combination of shell magic and `set table`.  For example:

```
set samples 200 #How many points will be used in interpolating the data...
YLIMIT=.5  #for example
set table 'junkfile1.dat'  #This holds the "smooth" portion
plot 'data_file' binary format='%uint64 %double %double %double' using 1:($2<YLIMIT ? $2: 1/0) smooth csplines
unset table                #This holds the "spurious" portion
set table 'junkfile2.dat'
plot 'data_file' binary format='%uint64 %double %double %double' using 1:($2>YLIMIT ? $2: 1/0)
unset table

plot '< sort -n -k 1 junkfile1.dat junkfile2.dat' u 1:2 with lines 
!rm junkfile1.dat junkfile2.dat  #cleanup after ourselves
```

(Untested)

Comment: problem is that the sort and other functions work only on ascii data and not on binary day. i am trying to modify the graph format and check with the code listed above.

Comment: Are you referring to `plot '<sort -n -k 1 ...`?  Set table should output ASCII datafiles (which are generated by gnuplot from your binary ones).  Those ASCII files are then read back into gnuplot in the last plot command (after filtering the data through sort which should accept the ASCII files gnuplot generated.)

Comment: i tried the above method. it works for small inputs but for bigger inputs, it crashes showing out of memory error for the table.

Comment: Wow, you really must have a lot of data points (or a small amount of memory).  I think the question you should be asking is then, do you really need that much data?  Once your point density becomes too high (For example, when you have more points than pixels on your screen), you don't really gain much by packing in more points.